# How to get # line of statement encountered error in stored procedure in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

How could I get the # line of a statement encountered error in a stored procedure in postgresql?

Stored procedure has an exception as shown here (it throws error message and state - but no line information):

```
EXCEPTION  
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE NOTICE '%   % ', sqlstate ,  sqlerrm ; 
    END;
```

Comment: See Documentation on [Obtaining Execution Location Information](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CALL-STACK).